# Has kendo-ui web a viewport control like sencha ext js has it

Tags: extjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

With sencha ext js I can wrap my datagrid in a viewport widget set to layout: fit which means the grid has a height of 100% and the vertical scrollbars are visible on the grid so the column headers stay fixed when vertically is scrolled.

```
Ext.widget('viewport', {
    layout: 'fit'
    ,items: [{
        xtype: 'grid'
        // ... your grid config
    }]
});
```

I have googled about the kendo-ui grid and also did a sample project where I could not achieve that the grid has a height of 100% and show vertical scrollbars the same time. The height of the kendo ui grid must be set in pixel. But sencha ext js allow to set kind of 100% height for the grid by using such a viewport widget.

Does such a widget also exist for kendo ui?

Comment: nobody knows? Maybe there is a workaround somehone has found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code from the kendo ui documents:

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/grid/walkthrough

```
$(window).resize(function () {

            var gridElement = $("#grid"),
                newHeight = gridElement.innerHeight(),
                otherElements = gridElement.children().not(".k-grid-content"),
                otherElementsHeight = 0;

            otherElements.each(function () {
                otherElementsHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
            });

            gridElement.children(".k-grid-content").height(newHeight - otherElementsHeight);
        });
```

Not as flexible to use as the viewport from ext js but I am really glad they provide a workaround :)